# handle link_to external parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a link that have external `data-offset` parameter:

```
<%= link_to "Load more", something_path, :remote => true, :"data-offset" => 30 %>
```

Is it possible to get and handle `data-offset` in controller in ajax action? If no, is there any similar solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should end up with a `data-offset` parameter in the HTML you can access with JavaScript. In jQuery you might do this:

```
var data_offset = $('a[data-offset]').attr('data-offset');
```

Comment: I am using Prototype and Rails built-in AJAX functionality

Comment: It's doable in Prototype too, but since Prototype lacks the convenience methods jQuery provides, you will have to do it the hard way. Give your link an ID for Prototype to latch on to so you can select it. This is one of a hundred reasons why jQuery is better than Prototype, so unless you're heavily invested in Prototype, it would be easier to switch early.